# Python find all words with n character equal to certain letter

Tags: python, regex

Can you help? It is an easy task but I am stuck.
I want to find all words with the fourth letter 'x'.

```
z = 'hlello wle xcra cexx extra ssx ssbx'
re.findall(r'\b.{3}x', z)
```

expected output

```
['cexx', 'ssbx']
```

current ouput

```
[' cex', ' ssx', 'ssbx']
```

Comment: "*I want to find all words with the third letter 'e'.*": You mean "*x*" as the fourth?

Comment: @InSync right, ´x´ not ´e´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track by using `re.findall`, but you should use the regex pattern:

```
\b\w{3}x\w*
```

Sample script:

```
z = 'hlello wle xcra cexx extra ssx ssbx'
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w{3}x\w*', z)
print(matches)  # ['cexx', 'ssbx']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `\b` a word boundary
- `\w{3}` any three word characters
- `x` the 4th letter as `x`
- `\w*` zero or more word characters

Comment: The last `\b` is not necessary; `\w*` takes up every word character it finds, so it never ends in the middle of `\w\w`.

Comment: @LJo Please reply to the comment under your question.  What is your goal here?